# Who has a working example of Spring+Hibernate+2LC Infinispan+JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-transactions, infinispan

I'm banging my head all morning already to replace EHCache by Infinispan. I've tried many configurations with different releases. But always it seems there's a missing link somewhere between Hibernate and Spring about transaction management. To my own shame I have to admit I can't seem to find the way to make this work together.

I'm using the classic solution of Spring (3.1) backed by JPA and Hibernate (4.0.1). With EHCache as 2nd level & query cache. All deployed on a standalone Tomcat 7.

Is somebody in here willing to share a working Spring configuration for this ?

Many thanks !

I'm including the Spring configuration - in case of an obvious flaw somewhere ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd

          http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Scan our code for Spring annotations @Component, @Repository and @Service annotated classes are added -->
  <!-- to the Spring configuration as if they're declared in this file. -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" scoped-proxy="targetClass"/>


  <!-- configuration transactions are done with @Transactional -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Describes how to connect to the database -->
  <!-- Describes to reuse database connections as making them is expensive -->
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="user" value="${database.user.name}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.user.password}"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="4"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Describes how to create hibernate sessions -->
  <!-- "persistenceUnitName" points to META-INF/persistence.xml -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="foo"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Exception when using org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTSStandaloneTransactionManagerLookup for the transaction lookup class.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unable to start region factory
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not obtain JBoss Transactions transaction manager instance
    at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.tm.HibernateTransactionManagerLookup.getTransactionManager(HibernateTransactionManagerLookup.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:274)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform.java:46)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 81 more
```

Exception after adding the dependency (quite a lot of indirect dependencies came with it)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: Hmmm, what's the problem or issue that you have right now? Any exceptions?

Comment: Just a sec, I'm redoing the changes. In the meantime, does the configuration looks okay for a standalone implementation ? Thanks for helping btw ! :-)

Comment: There you are:the exception. It's probably thé stupid detail that is missing. I want the caches to be transactional. But they should use the transaction manager of the Spring application context. So it's probably me messing up the configuration. But where ... ?

Comment: Based on http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-transactionstrategy, seems to be you have to use: org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTSStandaloneTransactionManagerLookup

Comment: We're getting somewhere. Apparently a library is missing. :-)

Comment: Yeah, missing JBoss ts library, add the following dependency:

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
   <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
   <version>4.16.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Added the next stack trace. Maybe it's a bit ambitious to have transactional caching for Spring/Hibernate/Infinispan nowadays. That's a pity. Is there a way to disable transactional support for Infinispan ?

Comment: I've posted the same question at Spring. But nobody answers. So maybe Infinispan is not that common yet... http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?122582-Infinispan-transaction-configuration-problem

Comment: And created a ticket https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-162. You would think that if somebody knows about this, it's there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement to run jpa + l2 cache + infinispan in Tomcat.

The following hibernate coniguration worked for me.

hibernate.cache.region.factory_class -> org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory
hibernate.transaction.jta.platform -> org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class -> org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.tm.HibernateTransactionManagerLookup

I had the following additional dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
    <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```